# how can communicate two SQL database in LAN to save data in both database

Tags: sql, replication

We have a server with SQL database (8 database) working in LAN, Now we are planning to make a backup server connected through LAN.

What we need is, when user enter data it should save in both database, so that we have all the data in both database.

I am a newbie so pls give me some detail information. I have seen some replication option, is it better option for us.

We have SQL Server 2005.

Comment: too little detail downvoted. Please add which SQL server product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Which database engine are you using?

There're several ways to build a distributed/replicated database, I'm sure you'll find out how to do it by reading your engine documentation, but we cannot help here without more info.

Comment: We have SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can backup your database from one server to other by multiple way.. Following are those
1) Make script of complete database with schema and data..Technique is [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/)
2) Export your database to excel file and import it to other server (Use only in required conditions).
3) communicate two server by addlink.. Technique [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

Now if you want dump data in two different server then its depend on code logic written for dumping database and connection string provided for it. By adding Trigger to one server database you can dump data on different server or database.. [Trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: Can you suggest me any way for SQL 2005 Server

Comment: Most of techniques mention in my answer is applicable for SQl server 2005 and above version. So u can use those in SQL Server 2005 also. For script generation is [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/16/sql-server-2005-generate-script-with-data-from-database-database-publishing-wizard/)